# Checking parity of a number in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand bitwise operation.
The parity is 1 if the number of 1s in the bit is odd and 0 otherwise.

In the following code:

```
def parity(x):
    res = 0
    while x:
        res ^= x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return result
```

This gives the correct result, but I am not sure how the bitwise tricks work.
I tried to write down the bit changes using the number, but still don't get the intuition of solving this problem.

Why would we check `XOR` with `x & 1` and what do they even mean?

Comment: `x & 1` does a bitwise AND of `x` and `1`.  In other words, its value is the low-order bit of `x`, either `0` or `1`.  This is then XORed into `res`.  Then `x` is right-shifted by one, and the process is repeated until all bits have been handled.

Comment: What's the significance of XOR here?

Comment: @Dawn17 The exclusive-OR ensures that the result cycles between 0 and 1 as the loop shifts through the bits of x.  Trace the state of res on a small input x and you will start to see the pattern.

Comment: @Dawn17 You're trying to compute parity by determining whether there's an even vs. odd number of `1` bits.  XOR does exactly that:  If you XOR a `0` into your parity, the parity is unchanged.  If you XOR a `1` into your parity, the parity is complemented (`0` becomes `1` and `1` becomes `0`).  You can easily work this out on paper.

Comment: @Dawn17 To put it another way, parity is (or can be) *defined* to be the XOR of all the bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, the first initialization of 'res' is to set our res-state as even.  This make sense because we haven't evaluated any bits yet and 0 is even.

Then we move to the while loop where we shift through the bits of x.

Now, we evaluate each bit of x by AND-comparing it with 1 to tell us if it is also a 1 (`x&1`).  Then with the results of that comparison, we compare against the current res-state (`res^=(x&1)`).

- If res is even (0) and x-bit is 1, res evaluates to odd (1).
- If res is odd (1) and x-bit is 1, res evaluates to even (0).
- Else res does not change.

And in this way we can ensure res flips between even and odd according to the parity of x.

This **truth table** is also helpful for thinking about the problem:

```
res x  XOR out
 0  0  ->   0 // This is the state of even and no 1's found
 0  1  ->   1 // This is the state of even and then a 1 is found
 1  0  ->   1 // This is the state of odd and no 1's found
 1  1  ->   0 // This is the state of odd and then a 1 is found
```

Hope that helps!